# What does 二人 and 揃う mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

I was watching the manga events and came across this line, when the actors said

[image]

> 今年もこのスーパーステージに二人の日向と影山が**揃いました**よ!

[Audio Link](https://clyp.it/cud4mc0h)

He was referring to 日向 and 影山, who are the protagonists of the story.

**Q1**: I know that 二人 means 2 people. However, although there are 4 people on the stage,

2 of them are an actor for 日向 (1 stage actor and 1 voice actor). Similarly, another 2 are

an actor for 影山. Thus I was curious if he was referring to

> A: 2 people, who are 日向 and 影山?
>
> or
>
> B: 2 日向 and 2 影山?

**Q2**: I know that 揃いました is a past tense of 揃う, which seems to have 3 different meanings

based on [Jisho](http://jisho.org/search/%E6%8F%83%E3%81%86).

> A: to be complete; to be all present; to make a full set; to be satisfied (of conditions)​
>
> B: to be equal; to be uniform; to be even; to match; to agree​
>
> C: to gather; to assemble; to be collected​

However, because of the confusion from Q1, I'm not so sure about the actual meaning of

**揃う** in this context.

I'm pretty sure I'm overthinking this, but it would be great if I can get a further clarification..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1**: It's "2 Hinatas and 2 Kageyamas". Of course it's ambiguous and the same phrase can mean "2 Hinatas and (one) Kageyama", but people who have background knowledge about this manga can easily choose the correct meaning. If you want to say "two people, (who are) Hinata and Kageyama", that would be "日向と景山の2人", not "2人の日向と景山".

> - 2人の男
>     two men
> - 男と女の2人
>     two people, one man and one woman

**Q2**: This 揃う is used in the sense of A and C at the same time, "for everyone to gather".